# Listview showing strange behavior

Tags: android, android-listview

**What I have**

My app has only one activity and all other are fragments
One of the fragment displays a listview that is populated from datbase through a cursor adapter.

**My Problem**

Everytime the screen rotates or i return back to the app after pressing home button, what i see is that I have another listview that lies over another one i.e another same listview is also populated over pre existing one.

**Here is my code**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_list_frag, container, false);
    Log.d("HirakDebug", "tasksListFrag View Created");
    tasks_Database_Operations tasksDatabaseOperations = new tasks_Database_Operations(getActivity());
    Cursor cursor = tasksDatabaseOperations.readData();
    taskslist = (SwipeListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tasks_list);
    adapter = new tasksCursorAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY);
    taskslist.setAdapter(adapter);
    delete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteAll);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    taskslist.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosed(int position, boolean fromRight) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onListChanged() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMove(int position, float x) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {
            Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartOpen %d - action %d", position, action));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartClose(int position, boolean right) {
            Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartClose %d", position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onClickBackView(int position) {
            Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickBackView %d", position));
            taskslist.closeAnimate(position);//when you touch back view it will close
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(int[] reverseSortedPositions) {

        }

    });


    taskslist.setSwipeMode(SwipeListView.SWIPE_MODE_RIGHT); // there are five swiping modes
    // there are four swipe actions
    taskslist.setSwipeActionRight(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL);
    taskslist.setOffsetRight(convertDpToPixel(80f)); // right side offset
    taskslist.setAnimationTime(500); // Animation time
    // enable or disable SwipeOpenOnLongPress

    Log.d("HirakDebug", "tasksListFrag Adapter set");

    return view;
}

public int convertDpToPixel(float dp) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return (int) px;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("HirakDebug", "taskListFrag resumed");
    getRetainInstance();
}

@Override
public void setRetainInstance(boolean retain) {
    super.setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("LifeCycle", "tLF Pause");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("LifeCycle", "tLF Stop");
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.d("LifeCycle", "tLF DestroyView");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("LifeCycle", "tLF Destroy");
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    Log.d("LifeCycle", "tLF Detach");
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Log.d("LifeCycle", "tLF Attach");
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d("LifeCycle", "tLF Start");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d("LifeCycle", "tLF saveInstance State");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == delete) {
        Log.d("HirakDebug", "Delete Button Pressed");
        tasks_Database_Operations tasksDatabaseOperations = new tasks_Database_Operations(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = tasksDatabaseOperations.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDatabase.delete(tasksDatabaseOperations.ASSIS_TASK_TABLE_NAME, null, null);
        Log.d("HirakDebug", "tLF All Data Deleted");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("HirakDebug", "tLF ArrayList Cleared");
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check inside your activity onCreate method

```
if (saveInstance == null) {
  mFragment = new Fragment();
  fm.beginTransaction().replace(mFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT).commit();
}
```

Comment: because on orientation change the complete life cycle of android activity is again called.

Comment: ohh. i got it. i was actually calling the fragment in activity's onResume method. so when orientation change or something occurs, not just the listview, but entire fragment was being added over the pre existing one

Comment: happy programming. :)